# recreating ext4 journal: reboot required?

Tags: filesystems, ext4

Most docs on disabling/creating the ext4 journal for root involve a reboot.  If we:

- turn off the journal via tune2fs
- fsck the filesystem
- turn the journal back on via tune2fs
- fsck the filesystem
- then reboot

Will that effectively re-create the journal?  In this specific case we have a corrupted journal we wish to re-initialize.  If we can eliminate the intervening reboot then we can better automate this process.

I don't actually see why a reboot is required at any point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your point would be excellent if it were not for the logical impossibility in steps two and four.  You cannot meaningfully `fsck` a mounted filesystem; they are made self-inconsistent by the very act of being mounted.  You can't unmount the partition to `fsck` it, because it's the root partition.  The `fsck` requirement, I suspect, is why all instructions involve a reboot or two.

Comment: "mount -o remount" in single user mode?

Comment: `mount -o remount,ro` would probably do it, but it'll essentially stop the machine from working.  I'd assumed you wanted to avoid a reboot because of service interruption; if you don't mind service interruption, why not reboot and do it cleanly?

Comment: A service interruption is fine, the purpose is to better automate the process.

Comment: OK, then modify your procedure above; looks like we might be iterating towards a solution!